# Diablo III, anniversary exp bonus bug?

Tags: diablo-iii

I have a **0%** experience bonus on my level 70 Demon Hunter and my level 56 Crusader.

And yes, I've verified that this is not just a display issue; my heroes gain the same experience killing monsters that they did yesterday.

I would like to know whether this **0%** bonus is intended before reporting a bug to reclaim my bonus tomorrow or whatever Blizzard team decide to do.

By the way, if there is a reason explaining why a player could have **0%** bonus I would like to know the url of the official page where it is explained.

[image]

Comment: I also removed the **random** bolding of words, because it didn't **add** anything.

Comment: @Arperum yes, that ***was*** kind of **annoying**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a [reddit post](http://www.reddit.com/r/Diablo/comments/25in42/diablo_3_two_year_anniversary_drop_buff/) that seems to translate the announcement from Blizzard's Korean Site, but it can also be found on the English site [here](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/14005211):

> To celebrate the game's second anniversary and the community that made it all possible, players who log in to defend Sanctuary this week **will receive double Rift Fragments as well as a +100% boost to their chance to find Legendary items**. This bonus birthday buff begins in the Americas on Thursday, May 15 at 12:00 a.m. PDT and ends on Thursday, May 22 at 5:00 a.m. PDT.

(emphasis mine)

It does not say anything about an Experience Boost. I think it is included (as 0%) in the tooltip is that this buff (icon) and tooltip use a standard template.

It definitely is not a bug, as you are not supposed to have an experience boost, just Legendary Drops and Rift Fragments.

Comment: So basically Blizzard developers preffers to show "You have 0% exp bonus" instead hidding that useless information that will only 'cause people like me to think that maybe it is a bug and collapse blizzard's support system. I really can't understand in what are thinking these developers. Thanks for your answer

Comment: Yes, seems like it. Luckily I stopped trying to understand what Blizzard is thinking a long time ago. Saves a lot of braincells.

Comment: @ElektroStudios They probably just reused the existing community bonus buff and didn't update the tooltip.  Modifying the bonus (e.g. 50% exp -> 100% exp or making it affect legendary drop rates) can be done on the server.  Updating tooltips usually requires a client patch (because it has to be localized and all that), so they may have figured it's not worth the effort.  Takes a lot of work to make a client patch and this buff is only for a week.  Next event may be some totally different bonus.